# Display Image after Upload

Tags: php

Here is my uploadImage.php. I want to display the image right after they upload it.
The problem is that I don't what seems to be the problem. I tried to alter some of it, and come to this code. But still not getting my expected result. Anyone care to help me?

```
   <?php

   $tempFile = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
   $name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
   $uploadDirectory = "/home/trainee/Desktop/tmp/";

   $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
   $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
   $extension = end($temp);
   if ((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/gif")
   || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
   || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
   || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
   || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
   || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png"))
   && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 20000)
   && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
   {
     if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
     {
       echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br>";
     }
     else
     {
       echo "Upload: " . $name. "<br>";
       echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br>";
       echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
       echo "Temp file: " . $tempFile . "<br>";

       if (file_exists("$uploadDirectory" . $name))
       {
         echo $name . " already exists. ";
       }
       else
       {
     move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "$uploadDirectory/$name"),
     $name
         echo "Stored in: " ."$uploadDirectory". $name;
       }
    }
 }
 else {
 echo "invalid File!";
 }
 ?>
 <img src="upload/<?php=$name?>" height=200 width=100">
```

Comment: Sidenote: This line is broken `move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "$uploadDirectory/$name"), $name echo "Stored in: " ."$uploadDirectory". $name;` - [Read the manual](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) on the `move_uploaded_file()` function. Once you've established the correct variable(s), you just echo it.

Comment: You lost me there buddy. So It'll be like  echo "Stored in: " .move_uploaded_file($tempFile, "$uploadDirectory/$name"), Is this correct?

Comment: See the answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another post that may help.
[how to preview uploaded image in php form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19947355/how-to-preview-uploaded-image-in-php-form)

As far as I know, there's really no way to preview the image until it's been uploaded.  And since we don't want a page reload or to have the user submit the form before we preview their upload, we need to use ajax.

There are quite a few ajax (javascript + php) options and tutorials for uploading and previewing an image before submitting the form. Here's a tutorial that may help.

- http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix of your code:

```
<?php
$tempFile = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
$uploadDirectory = "/home/trainee/Desktop/tmp/";

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$allowedFileTypes = array("image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/pjpeg",
        "image/x-png", "image/png");
if (in_array($_FILES["image"]["type"], $allowedFileTypes)
    && $_FILES["image"]["size"] < 20000
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
  if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
  {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Upload: " . $name. "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $tempFile . "<br>";

    if (file_exists($uploadDirectory . $name))
    {
      echo $name . " already exists. ";
    }
    else
    {
      move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $uploadDirectory . $name);
      echo "Stored in: " . $uploadDirectory . $name;
    }
  }
}
else
{
  echo "invalid File!";
}
?>
<img src="upload/<?php echo $uploadDirectory . $name; ?>" height="200" width="100">
```

> **NOTE:** *Your upload directory must should be accessible from web user. Currently it seems not accessible!* :(

Comment: How can I enable it? And the only output that I am getting is "Invalid File" even though I am uploading a .jpg file

Comment: Upload your files in `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/some-directory/upload-directory`. And for `Invalid file` check your validation by echoing each conditional expression.

Comment: is there any documentation for that? So I could no longer bother you? Thank you :)